# How to SQL query a nested list and array in a MS Azure CosmosDB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have the following (*Azure*) **CosmosDB** (sub) structure, that has 2 nested arrays:

```json
{
    "id": "documentTypes",
    "SomeThing": "SomeThing",
    "configuration": [
        {
            "language": "en",
            "list": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Supporting Documents"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Summary PDF"
                },
            ]
        }
    ],
}
```

I have tried the following queries, with poor results.

```sql
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.documentTypes.configuration[0].list[0].id FROM c
```

and

```sql
SELECT
    p.id,       
    p.name
FROM f
    JOIN c IN f.configuration
    JOIN p IN c.list
WHERE c.id == 'documentTypes'
```

---

**`Q`**: **How can I get only the list of `name` and `id`s?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this?

```sql
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT VALUE e FROM c JOIN d IN c["configuration"] JOIN e IN d["list"]) AS Result FROM c
```

**Output:**

> [
> {
> "Result": [
> {
> "id": 1,
> "name": "Supporting Documents"
> },
> {
> "id": 2,
> "name": "Summary PDF"
> }
> ]
> } ]

Comment: Indeed that partially worked, but gave too many results from other parts of the DB. Adding `WHERE c.id = 'documentTypes'` fixed the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

My own solution was similar to *Sajeetharan*'s:

```sql
SELECT list.id, list.name FROM c
    JOIN configuration IN c.configuration 
    JOIN list IN configuration.list
WHERE c.id = 'documentTypes'
```

This to me look a bit simpler by not needing `[""]` and the `ARRAY()` function, and also doesn't produce the additional `Result` item. I have not idea if there is any performance difference.