# Query Nested Array in Cosmos DB

Tags: arrays, azure-cosmosdb

I'm new to Cosmos and I am trying to query a *nested* array. I found this [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/understanding-how-to-query-arrays-in-azure-cosmos-db/?ref=morioh.com&utm_source=morioh.com) on how to work with arrays but there isn't an example on a nested array.

Given this json document, how can I query the `Tags` array? I want to find all records that have a tag of "test-1" within its `Fees` array.

```
{
    "id": "22142846",
    "PartitionKey": 846,
    "Fees": [
        {
            "Tags": [
                "test-1"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Tags": [
                "test-2"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why would you have an array with the same name twice vs. having it once with both values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to SQL query a nested list and array in a MS Azure CosmosDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71691277/how-to-sql-query-a-nested-list-and-array-in-a-ms-azure-cosmosdb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the sample query

```
SELECT c.id, c.PartitionKey
FROM c
JOIN t IN c.Fees
where array_contains(t.Tags,"test-1")
```

Here is the result.

[image]

Sample Records/Documents used

```
{
    "id": "22142846",
    "PartitionKey": 846,
    "Fees": [
        {"Tags": ["test-1"]},
        {"Tags": ["test-2"]}
    ]
}


{
    "id": "22142847",
    "PartitionKey": 847,
    "Fees": [
        {"Tags": ["test-1"]},
        {"Tags": ["test-2"]}
    ]
}

{
    "id": "22142848",
    "PartitionKey": 848,
    "Fees": [
       {"Tags": ["test-2"]},
       {"Tags": ["test-3"]}
    ]
}
```